# How to use avalonEdit control 3 Questions

Tags: c#, wpf, avalonedit

I'm building a Html code editor with WPF and I use avalonEdit control, my 3 Questions are.

1. how to create collapse code like in the picture I attached (the plus and minus signs)?
2. how to get the current line number and text (all the text in the current line)?
3. is it possible to do a tooltip for some of the words in the document?

[image]

Comment: Did you try looking at the documentation?  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42490/Using-AvalonEdit-WPF-Text-Editor

Comment: of course. I worked on it for hours without Results.

Comment: then you should probably pick 1 of your questions, document what you tried, what didn't work, and what your expected results are.  As it stands now, it comes across as a "write the code for me" type of request.

Comment: Sorry if it looks like that. but I could not do anything and I tried for hours.

Comment: Have you tried browsing for the collapsible code in the sample: https://github.com/icsharpcode/AvalonEdit/tree/master/ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit.Sample

Comment: the sample for collpsible code dont work good. only one code block work good.